# PDF file streaming in IE from server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to open a PDF file in IE 9 browser from another server. The PDF file is not streamed properly. The file opens perfectly fine in Chrome.

I am using webclient for download.
I don't want to save the file to local drive.

Here is my code

List OcDialerlfinfo = null;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
          OcDialerlfinfo = GetFileList("*.pdf", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DocumentsLocation"].ToString());

```
}

protected void btnpdf_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (FileInfo fi in OcDialerlfinfo)
    {
        if (fi.Name == "S1127183-01.pdf")
        {
            WebClient User = new WebClient();
            Byte[] FileBuffer = User.DownloadData(fi.FullName);
            if (FileBuffer != null)
            {
                Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", FileBuffer.Length.ToString());
                Response.BinaryWrite(FileBuffer);
            }
        }
    }
}


public static List<FileInfo> GetFileList(string fileSearchPattern, string rootFolderPath)
{
    DirectoryInfo rootDir = new DirectoryInfo(rootFolderPath);

    List<DirectoryInfo> dirList = new List<DirectoryInfo>(rootDir.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories));
    dirList.Add(rootDir);

    List<FileInfo> fileList = new List<FileInfo>();

    foreach (DirectoryInfo dir in dirList)
    {
        fileList.AddRange(dir.GetFiles(fileSearchPattern, SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly));
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

The file opens as shown below`

```
%PDF-1.5 %âãÏÓ 10 0 obj <> endobj 147 0 obj <>/Filter/FlateDecode/ID[]/Index[10 194]/Info 9 0 R/Length 364/Prev 2234655/Root 11 0 R/Size 204/Type/XRef/W[1 3 1]>>stream hÞì“Í+DaÆß÷Þ™0E“¬)vÊ4‹ÙXÐ(i¶Jb1 +ÙÙ°5›)±R†ñÍø¸>R,H"YØPó70KîùÝÉ=eikóëé9ç<ç}ßÛu¬1qãš~¡m„µ°?…uYŸ‘)+Ì{ÂŽ„O7“y½ü(z|Eô}L¦b3$,’ß §qºÐIÅÀIQM)GÑêÎ¤êW9vöÝ–_ù:'Ø"Ö‰‡=ÎÎ)9c°ŒÓ«ª#ø“’h#y ®’“Cï ç„5ªç ?ÔKèküš)³Ž~ÜÃß@çeûC+zžS=F—Bß0eƒAõÿHØÅ¹ ª9ÁÔ‰ª–Õ ç¡$ØÑ§mÒèCxyIóÊë¹è"þÜ¶gÑ$›’ºo)L«Þº¨2õ ƒê¼dW%¬V7zêMvÃ3L¢»™­§g § Þù|k~7Žÿïð½|ïŸâ—q ·ß ½8VC endstream endobj startxref 0 %%EOF 203 0 obj <>stream hÞl‘1H#a„¿÷7»‚‰QŒ"ê’ã E$EŠ€áX1¨ESÚk,<Žã´3V>ETÄR±“pµ  à•{……XZF8Ž+,R¦ô7Z(80Ì{ó†i° Ú²Ö)ïaj\q÷Þ˜»¯„<Ý Dv…EIø©åá‹…biL/Þ¼»½ÊdŽO­Cì‚IzBâ¹-$†%T^æ¶•3b¬œ¹Œ”Õš´SDÆŠc…‰sõÓ¤ô QÿoëŒªx‡ê˜|uåƒ]§J²®VíPœŠJã£gç¾‘öÕ=ã8«ªD»EÎ¥‰ˆ/¸uÇì¤°zÄ Ž~ñIt…}’ «âMÉÚ_:!%…y&ñ|ÕÉˆÄj¬Óªÿ½ýâ„*fêu[$Q™§© áµ8 š®¢¸B‹aÑ>Û^©¡‹üç\]óùOA‘]¶vÚ/Èö.¾ì*þ$ÀeÇJK endstream endobj 11 0 obj <> endobj 12 0 obj <> endobj 13 0 obj <>/Subtype/Form/Type/XObject>>stream H‰2T0Â w. s#=csSCCcc =S3c…\. ÓÂY0‡+˜ Àþ 7 endstream endobj 14 0 obj <>/Subtype/Form/Type/XObject>>stream 1 0 0 RG 871.3278 1330.2018 m 892.2732 1328.6309 l S endstream endobj 15 0 obj <>/Subtype/Form/Type/XObject>>stream 1 0 0 RG 873.4224 1315.54 m 895.9386 1313.4456 l S endstream endobj 16 0 obj <>stream hÞìXíR9}‚}óc ¶Ü­Ï–Dˆ§ˆóQl…à Ù©Ýòò£±ÛÀŒ±]v³}ç}‡=WvwÈVÍÏIB|OKº÷H:¨,´cœ íþ ÃYe>³aÉ„òô@¡£'šI!€Œa‚Š¡ 5YÊ"p*ƒÀ#ðÈQq¦¹DJ ÐèSIV#PL Ž<•F ƒéEU!p4Ü2-9JTª€¯ÄPa‘Yzdm­2[dV™-2+š Êhå‘Ù"³–Èl‘YêƒÌÚQd6‚ò ³¡Y8d6 %Ð¬ -¨èJ CæJ#Cæ …CfK‹àÙÒÜ2[š»Cf')!2;Ì[€.Ö™‘T{jB?íi:^1Ã%5iTÝfóš—·ÌHNCzfªKÎ`* j´$¤Ñsö9ìqüéS¦O•>5}^•ÇCü÷  ý~9‰ƒãÏE9XÌÛfÞ®÷±R·Wå`ÕÔíÍbþ¶n›ý·‡à ç^`/MõW.æüçƒò=ÓåÇ‘³²PØ¡”+xÅœÃV3á‹òôq†Š«M†O§ûÒq5½T¦7½¼ä=-­ìùj*{¶n„®ÑH/Ê!anåp±¼[æ™—ŸûG¿<ÜÎØ¿›Õ|_ïaZ{¿ô.“¯ óõë½ë¶]–åýý}q¯ŠÅêªÄ*ûòáº½íÅN‡ÓúQGàÐs=¾nnë°7©ÛºDúc¦õáñðä×\ôx¼Z\Öí¡à…(\l_/›ñë=YðBî±þÑ’MnV¯÷fíj¯´^Öó-fëöë¬y½7Å&ôÖ7ÿi(_¶¯Úæ¡íÕ³›«ùá¬™¶¯Æ‹Ùbuø^…î÷ÿúKssuÝÎ«Ûz†|éÉ^?léQI5ûGå?´8ýƒòs3nG®ª wOøýw^&ìžF€Ý;¿»ümÿãçM}@qûuÙ”oæMùe|[¯Ú›¹8(¿ÐÓãù|ÑöûÚ{&]y¶lælZÏÖM9¬WPKº…ç® cHŠ …ß®€³lr±°ãO+d=ëô,ÅK‚®&hQ(:½”ÂæaEd!q <+*õ\ÏÂ|«guivµë94÷ôDšžcÕ³´Æ8?Åñ¶CÏòO=ÿ žã–~GÐ¦pa÷¤*pÞ9o ¶O™Âþ±zŽçîS=s_hùž%áÔ³yIÏüE=KñLÏ èõ/LW‚ó¦ðŠ˜ 4˜ç‚–þÑí-Ÿ¸±ï)íp@{ë{®æ¢Ç›K×xQMÝTï´þSÐ?*hþ‚ máÃöq†y. ¶Ob²úV´Ú¡h8˜G÷VÑ‚ð ŠÐZœ/ëqC`M¶®’’ˆà,Á]& ‚ÃL@—™€ N3*¸Ílpœ D×™€Î3‚àY3)‚M@š@t¢ èàF0Á‘&PWš€ Î4èNðÁ¡F xp© D§š€ n5kÑµ&`‚sM  î5l.¸Ø¢“@óàfÁÑ& ƒ«M@g›@t· ˜àp¨‚Ë  ×‡»`zcìƒï§Ú»‡öÃy‹# ’øp.‚¦^ÎeðÂ1VÁÇXGGW‹ñyÓŽÊáÛ÷åÉm}Õ âÇ ¤x]OnæWÈ{~­ró³Ëß e—…}. 9ú\–ÔÈs]R#Ï…I—Ç•Bð\ovÁ3º:‹L€®Ï" {§Èèž+2ü.‘ àà"ÀÁ'Ä†¯™ ÉpâÜÍ@­È’gÎld&@wL™ ÐÅUf¸™.d&‰ ¹!@ö%3 ^™×O‚^Ð‹)ˆ6+ƒp‰È€n™t/T&á • XòmôªÉ Ð 3Gßrdtã×™}Ã 3G_tdt¥Ñ™ë*žýþ¨< ÞÔëfÂâ]àÉ|Ò<àA:ÒFÆÛÑÆY\¿MXË¸œ;ÚpJù®a,®õî&Ñ™0îÃŽ&Åâ®ìnÒÝ MwSÕÝd»Éw¯†ê^ Í;ÉkÑ=Jv7u­ ºk=*¦»ÖCjúö¨»žíœ¶î^Ý½"¦{EŒè¤oòŠœ7ËzîåðøÓ—³Oï~’\qaðñ÷Í£¾ÛÝÉÇ½»edÌóDÿlf³Åývtõ¼K»ZüÞÌ¶]ìó.Ç³oÚÝóöÁWøøMÿ¼Ã)ìÃ¼­·‹Ä¿7gr Íz(ÒG0øu»•x>øóÙßÎÐMs®¶ý¾»RrÊ»í½cÞÌêñïOW&çl˜üüÙð”‰òü8ÁóSºGÊèÑ7.¬\,c{0ìÛ®îþ¡Ô{÷È€~làº/ŒÜ²ð.nåÛÅm}3ápQ¾¿›iyh“t]ß,îæ“õèqßwóñbÒì§6p=’Ñv\<¹Ðl­öb±Bæ/pµæ8~igmp:ô— =àæ>ÑÄÂì¶åÂW»”&™×X¾ßÿŸ„ñ endstream endobj 17 0 obj <>stream H‰ì—Éª$ÉE÷ùñáíó°– Ñ²ÑBh‚|¥‚‚úû>×Ü#"+³Õ Aˆ/Ã|´áÚ5óO·°ý}»…»+y }t×kÚ>®¡P²Ke{ÜbÈÉùöK#Ç¶ÇûIÛŸ¶Ü’÷ˆc‹97ú¶û1ò¯?ßü9ýa›ylsu?VW­ÖŠ~ücØþúùöéÖCv¥ÅÍó×rv5Ämê|Þî·þð¶ßÿóöŸ¦õµ472Ëj­®ÆÈõ)2TÒ5ô¸†Fí.æÊPÍÝŽ}*ž/[Õ\,e«%ºšl ºæÅ…R¯û¥À1ôx×é;ù1%ï|/æÇäƒ«#n²¼¥Ké‡ã‹cöÕ%ÜnÙöÜ½Kü´àÐŸ›ÂˆÕùsÁÇ÷±Hj ²Èt)h0bawÞdQ¯‡EéÕ¢R’Jw™ FÂÌ±&® ÇU¿¹¬­Ùe¯ëp¾È˜Øct±×¥] ôèFÊä5}j@].»†r‘?jVH\Qç.B8î§çÐãÖGr¡? ï-s/y]}¿C§‚§¡–p~ØŽsOÿ¼ùðnáy;ëã?;ëþäéé‘‹"/OÏƒÿ=ý]R%VU—™*½RŸ&LSZ€Ï'·ÕWôžSå=4ïÕëµ¾½fÎýóë= ÿªÿVP®­SÁuJgÍÍª¥ùòjÚ ¤h³Ä¸µ¦¾ÁbÉ~ ¸ç@4ÖAöáÁèx>:u”ëÔ÷‘§cÅÐùºø8å\qÝÓ\ªO[ÞÎ-ß©´ïê&Gk.†ÜnÊª‡ž×åîþâîßJ¹ß}îÛýó¶Ï÷KÕàñ9ZÒñèç~´E®z»ê/ÚZçÖ°¶â×p¤ÜÃOì‘.|ØÌ‡|À+"·ÆsÛÉ®@°]¬ÛÞ¯…DˆŠÈÔÇ•­@HÜ/uGÏdŒcý!Ò9Œk2ÅyÈzÜBUC£ÛÀÚüæ‰PóW%ÑU›‚PíúÇSúñMì ô§o™²t…qS¨"wŒÜWÅï®Lk¼"÷âz[ßfÐ[3@3É€–Ê!«Š‰Ñµ&ðÆs[ºÛ3Ðvð¢ðSDbB¶S. *vÃÈQÖ7¸®}XüLt«¬ÃàæTf‚PF´–ÔÌ£D¸R{(`6ÊË[0D! ™'ç';£nœ+Ã°Ÿ>ÓËËSÝ¢5Žª” F{LèNþ'{Z„©u7Þªp›ðJR‘‰b?G-<r@7OI‘(Ê6!ÜÕyjØfnÄ™ß¹˜7j2_•éôJFò“¯æ>ÇdSRñÊã-ŸÎYE¤Ï¹ÞºíåàuX— Â(¥ÍI ¨£j)Áí±®àŒõãÛÐ¿•ç_uR£Ä:P§-®Vã2ãBâ8ihÀŸ“4ˆ½x6 ®RÒÒ¢šDŽùt¤°è@‰Ìqešì7KOf(… “,†Ñ¢ ,Xb4£Ú%Ö0Ž ®µd—'SQ _â?ÌßÐ¨•‰Ž_‹ªiiÞA!$[öœE:Ëú5ÉJîIö~µYÖëvL‚,9†6+&Ë¦µ±I¦ÒÎ[sÅFò‹—CvZ#ñ|·°¡‘ ­U}‚¡ÎÐù³ª¢‰OõfåMJø#ºªø T ‹Œ‹mÒc5o„fÈ³ë»c79(~¦Ó>Éâ êAU»h£J©Ïµ•‰YèRSé´Yaœ‚4­*ìÇÜ¬)E!²0±^¥hqlK ÛùJ»–<+'e÷`ÌG1)c»`gœ™- —ÅSP¨„\¼Qy6Ûî"LèÝr¹+FJ‡lÙô£»ª¥}3´OÁ[í3dãp?k”/Ð-ænQælƒå Þiqºð,‰µMärNÊ k_=€†õ( D4eg…¦õ©œ5ÚL«7ºÆÊš-Wf¶¹Ž™RE}N²º§DÍƒú“~Š3Êášž%_¢WZ}ãÇûºxY’‹°åŽl¼è'Ø)â`Übáíº×Ÿ,®˜©,¸ÑôU™ÔŠÖªÑ‹ºr¨§E>"#LtXX*®9¹½­ºg„WCµcÕ½Æh.¢¯›Ù= ªŒ±£ßÅ@ h¢OR`ªª2›+""ÒÔš¬!×«Œ,›bÊñ0™)ÂmºÒúŸ1ÚAUé¾Ø¬çcRÈƒ´8ºå¹t ¸DF«9)*Ð|% ’.‰³ÎÂ´Ój†•±½D%×ˆF¿0›”]Ü$:ØA» €"OŸÔ«^ÄGô8Ý+|M‹ãÄƒ5ŠËÔ/L7VËKŒò’’¡[qßyÄÀ®¢ÑÏM2t’ÄdÜOýRè¼ö$5«é‡L\ýœe /ŸhÍï!©»k%«ÖÅsÎÂ‘øýi ¡ì`EiUCÊ©1÷fPþÅìÙÔ°nËjdU—4µ¿¼4¦Nz eEÆXº(CÕ¾T[Š bÍš$Äu¶<’ŠòkIZ›ÕQž³Ó½3à{ b ‘i·@+<¸;7°ÃÛØ]¬ jâpŽÍI¶4IX0%’:¬~Ú6ý+Ÿ‰àåCñuUbl@¯Žé"ez‚è^‡¨*W#îfüõ:1cùÈôèâ?^‡äTþ8¶’÷7Õäb•õhY™–‰¢0Ø¬×ÉÊŠ¹VøÛôxTš·ª² ºG·ˆ7{rË+ÎµDzm6•†¤Ì ²fê¯vWŽ˜¶õIØUÙ‹ì!)1ŸêOpg‘ËL Š MBm3-,ipàPk²œÍNõe°áb[ËÝEè5>£#¡}XK¿ZOB{ ¯¨¹Àé(_Äy¦<- ôUPSO®ç!¼j/ãa#’d\M*ÀâËÁÈU ©¹àgŽêç¢ª‚”jþðr(€Å^® y:Ænš¯h‡ÝÙù÷9Æ7IsV$¡þ”ã3TÍŽXŽùƒ0ž n->C‹TÃ†¸yµ½™ô”kXÄZÔ9óøßiZÉWYŠU_l>ðwq{º£ájF×7ñˆ7Ð5è–ûnÌ‰hï’’ÝJüUµ¸ëìÿZo¶1y.+|Û­;"-Ó€à)®²¡Ã¼bÙSÃs÷ sÄ+ÙaÉlèŠ­;ì÷E­R.Ò; úøxQ«S=6õñ‹ HWZh5¡©Å?Ö"•›vŠn¤4tó•o¿|h½}åãþýRVHSÜ¯¢Tkú|ÅØ]ÿù#Ûº”ëßWÍìd[l${¿ xLÉüáñùCwï<>_ùòÃùÊï×ï—¦6¦ÁëŠû¤xæ·ómdy>~÷KgŒ``öqÎÞ™Í sÏ9Ë<ë·_+×??^ó,‡EO5ßãk–uG
```

Comment: AFAIK in IE9 you need some kind of plugin for PDFs to be displayed correctly (unless you use some kind of client based PDF viewer library, like `PDF.js` for example). Are you sure there is a PDF viewer plugin installed on the client you're testing? Or are you attempting to use `PDF.js` or a similar solution?

Comment: Thanks Bassfader..I installed PDF viewer and now I am getting "The file is damaged and could not be repaired". Please help.

Comment: The PDFs are opening now. I just cleared the history and its working fine., Thanks a lot